# Batch File : Clean every line from several files which doesn't have a String?

Tags: string, batch-file

I need to clean several txt files at once, cleaning all the lines which doesn't have a string mark. Need to be Windows batch file.

exemple:

```
set string="abcd"
for each *.txt file do (
  if line doesn't have string delete line
)
```

I don't want to generate new files, just update the original ones deleting the lines which doesn't have the string.

Of course you can create a temp file and overwrite the original one too without change the name. Doesn't matter how you do it, just the result is the same files but clean.

thank you

Comment: You have your pronouns mixed up. It does not matter how ***you*** modify the original file. It is your work after all. And if you search how to remove lines from a text file that contain a string, you will find many existing examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited fixing the errors, now it's working great! cheers!

```
@echo off

    set "string_to_find=some string"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do (
                set "tempfile=%temp%\%%a"
                if exist "%tempfile%" del "%tempfile%" >NUL
                findstr /C:"%string_to_find%" "%~dp0\%%a" >> "%tempfile%"
                if not errorlevel 1 (
                            del "%%a" >NUL
                            move /Y "%tempfile%" "%~dp0\%%a" >NUL
                            if exist "%tempfile%" del "%tempfile%" >NUL
                            echo File "%~dp0\%%a" processed successfully 
                ) else (
                echo Problem processing file "%~dp0\%%a"
                )
    )
```

Comment: is doing the opposite, is deleting the lines WITH the string,  but I want to keep them and delete the rest. Also is giving error say File is not a valid command on this line `File "%~dp0\%%a" processed successfully` also needs the line `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` before, or will simply delete the first file and give several errors. it's very close, how to invert the selection? thx

Comment: the error I fixed putting an `echo` before the line, seams just a print info right? seams a problem in the del/move commands which are saying the part that should be deleted and not saved, deleting what really interest. thx

Comment: removed the `/V` in the `findstr` command and works fine! thx

Comment: You are right, my mistake with /V option, and forget one 'echo'. Apology

Comment: `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` should not be necessary, because none of !vars! are used. But have not tested here...

Comment: you are right! don't need `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` thank you! :D

Comment: I'm having a WEIRD error, sometimes gives an error saying didn't found file/path... then after execute few times, simply work.

Comment: nevermind was just file permissions which were fixed if I execute another bat for testing and then yours only work after that. Giving and Removing the write protection fixed all the original files. cheers

Comment: little problem, if I run at CMD works fine, but if I simply double click on the file gives error that didn't found the files. Tryed to remove the ` \ ` on the parts `%~dp0\%%a` and aside also works in CMD still the same under windows. Exist a solution to this? thanks

Comment: Dunno why this simply stopped to work, now simply can't find the temp files, seams a problem with the temp files only... :(